# How to get widgets adjust size without adjust providing?

Tags: qt, size, qwidget, adjustment

I need to know the widget size if I call .adjust() method without actually call it.

How can I do this?

Comment: sizeHint() might help, but not in all cases. Maybe you're lucky and it works in your case?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld , yes it works! Thx!))))

Answer (score 0):

I used `.sizeHint()` and it helped in my case.